# Program will not compile, using arrays with structure objects

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to allow me to enter a string, and allow me to search for an employee by name, payrate, or id. However, it will not compile becuase of an error with the `strlen()` function.

The error I get is:

> main.cpp:88:39: error: cannot convert 'double' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

How can I fix this error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Employee
{
    int idNum;
    double payRate;
    char firstName, lastName;
};

int main()
{
    int error;
    const int SIZE = 5;
    Employee employee[SIZE];
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
    {
        employee[k].idNum = 0;
        employee[k].payRate = 0;
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
    {
        error = 0;
        cout << "Enter the employee's id number " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].idNum;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            if (employee[i].idNum == employee[count].idNum)
                error = 1;
        }
        while (error == 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter a new id number " << endl;
            cin >> employee[count].idNum;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
            {
                error = 0;
                if (employee[i].idNum == employee[count].idNum)
                    error = 1;

            }
        }
        cout << "Enter the employee's pay rate " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].payRate;
        cout << "Enter the employee's first name " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].firstName;
        cout << "Enter the employee's last name " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].lastName;
        int choice;
        cout << "Enter 1 to search for an employee by id number, enter 2 to                 search by last name, and enter 3 to search by pay "
             << endl;
        cin >> choice;

    }
    int choice;
    cout << "Enter 1 to search for an employee by id number, enter 2 to    search by last name, and enter 3 to search by pay "
         << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        int idNumC;
        cout << "Enter an id number ";
        cin >> idNumC;
        for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
        {
            if (employee[count].idNum == idNumC)
                cout << employee[count].idNum;
        }
    }
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        string name;
        cout << "Enter the employee's last name " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
        {
            if (strcmp(employee[count].lastName, name) == 0)
                cout << "ID number: " << employee[count].idNum
                        << " First name: " << employee[count].firstName
                        << " Last Name: " << employee[count].lastName
                        << " Hourly Pay: " << endl;
        }
    }
    if (choice == 3)
    {
        int nam;
        cout << "Enter the employee's last name " << endl;
        cin >> nam;
        for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
        {
            if (employee[count].payRate == nam)
                cout << "ID number: " << employee[count].idNum
                        << " First name: " << employee[count].firstName
                        << " Last Name: " << employee[count].lastName
                        << " Hourly Pay: " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [intro pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the one on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you write code, it is best to develop new functionality in isolation before you try to dovetail it into other code, and if you neglect that and run into a bug you should simplify the code as far as you can while preserving the bug. This is a vital coding skill.

Answer (score 0):

`employee[count].lastName` is a char, not a c-string (null terminated char array). Also, `name` is an `std::string`, not a c-string.

They must both be the same type to compare, so pick a type. If you want to make `lastName` an `std::string` then you can just do

```
if( employee[count].lastName == name )
```

Otherwise, if you make `lastName` a c-string, you'll need to make `name` one as well, so you can do:

```
if (strcmp(employee[count].lastName, name.c_str()) == 0)
```

Comment: I changed the type of data that firstName and lastName were to string, but that still does not fix my error

Comment: Did you read my answer about what else will have to change if you change to string? What is your error now?